# ArgumentError when running Capybara tests on Ruby 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am really stuck. I am upgrading my Rails app to Ruby 3 (from 2.7). When running tests, I always run into this issue when I `visit` a path:

```
state = "new"
visit status_path(state: “state")
```

I receive the following error when running rspec:

```
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 5.6.4 , codename: Birdie's Version
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:58568
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
from ~/.rbenv/versions/3.0.5/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:116:in `initialize'
```

My `Gemfile` is as such:

```
gem "capybara"              # 3.38.0
gem "selenium-webdriver"    # 4.8.0 
gem "webdrivers"            # 5.2.0
```

(They're all on the latest version)

My setup doesn't look wrong:

```
require "webdrivers/chromedriver"

Webdrivers.cache_time = 86_400 # 1 day

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.load_selenium

  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new.tap do |options|
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
  end

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end


Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

Troubleshooting:

- I tried Puma 6 - same issue.
- The controllers at `status_path` is not even hit. This errors occurs right after Puma loads up.
- I do not think it's the Capybara setup, and I just cannot find where it is calling the Ruby 3 library wrong (`net/protocol`).
- I downgraded `capybara` to 3.37.1, and same issue.

Thank you

Comment: Hoping the extra quotes is a typo here, visit status_path(state: state")

Comment: @Bijendra yes, typo in the question. Corrected. Thank you.

Comment: Would you be able to share the full stacktrace and not just the first line?

Comment: This looks like the Rails server is crashing on startup in which case capybara, selenium etc are irrelevant. What happens if you run `rails s -e test`? Does it run properly in other environments? What does the log tell you?

Comment: @spickermann that’s all I see, I’ve not chopped anything off …

Comment: In `Rails/log` folder you should have a `test.log` file. Open it and watch the last lines. Also if you work on linux, you may tail this file in order to see the last puma logs as they happen : `tail log/test.log` Maybe you have some info there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI Upgrading from 2.7 to 3 you will more often than not see this error. It's highly likely that some code you were previously using in 2.7 will be not correctly hashing some args.

The first hit when googling this will take you back to SO (Won't share link as SO doesn't like links). But to paraphrase from the official ruby byline when updating

> Separation of positional and keyword arguments in Ruby 3.0:

> In most cases, you can avoid incompatibility by adding the double splat operator. It explicitly specifies passing keyword arguments instead of a Hash object. Likewise, you may add braces {} to explicitly pass a Hash object, instead of keyword arguments.

TL;DR - Try doing splatting your hash args collection `kwargs` -> `**kwargs` - Your rails path likely isn't a kwarg but a hash --> `{ key: value }`

EDIT: Reasoning (If you're interested), is that prior to ruby3. Ruby would try assess and guesstimate what you meant. From ruby3 onwards it has made a change and fill forcibly use what you give it (A lot of people used to use kwargs but wanted them treated as a single hash, now you need to stipulate this!)